# Guest/temp accounts- remove change password link

Tags: customer, user

We have an e-commerce site powered by Magento. Products are displayed without prices, until a user logs in to their account, when the prices are displayed. We have a temporary guest account that potential customers are given details of, so they can log in and see prices. This guest account has the potential for a guest user to change the password to the account, which would render the account useless to others. Is there anyway to disable the 'change password' link on this one account?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There may be a few solutions. As the one of them, create a customer attribute, for example `hide_change_password_link` and give it a title 'Hide change password link'.
Next, go to the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml` file and replace the code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getChangePasswordUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></a>
```

with this one:

```
<?php if (!$this->getCustomer()->getData('hide_change_password_link')):?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getChangePasswordUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Change Password') ?></a><?php endif;?>
```

Replace all the templates where 'Change Password' string is.  For 1.9.0.1 they are:

- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml
- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml

**UPD.:** Also you need to override `Mage_Customer_AccountController`'s `editAction` like this:

```
/**
 * Forgot customer account information page
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_edit');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
    }
    $data = $this->_getSession()->getCustomerFormData(true);
    $customer = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $customer->addData($data);
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('changepass') == 1) {
        if ($this->getCustomer()->getData('hide_change_password_link')) {
           $message = 'You\'re not allowed to change the password.';
           Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
        } else {
           $customer->setChangePassword(1);
        }
    }

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Account Information'));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(true);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Also you have to override `editPostAction` (the same controller):

```
/**
 * Change customer password action
 */
public function editPostAction()
{
   $this->getRequest()->setParam( 'change_password', !$this->getCustomer()->getData('hide_change_password_link') && $this->getRequest()->getParam('change_password') );
   parent::editPostAction();
}
```

Hope it helpful!

Comment: This is a good start, but you need to disable the server side action also. hiding a link won't do much good if someone really want's to change the password. I can find my way around in 15 seconds or less even if there is no link.

Comment: Oh, sure, you're right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's more like it. +1.